# How many buckets options are there for putting N balls in the buckets?

Tags: combinatorics

N balls and how many buckets you want. You want to put the N balls into buckets. **How many buckets options are there?**

For example, (N=)4 balls can be put in the following ways:

- {1,1,1,1} - 1 ball into each bucket
- {1,1,2} - 2 buckets with 1 ball and 1 bucket with 2 balls
- {2,2} - 2 buckets with 2 balls
- {1,3} - 1 bucket with 1 ball and 1 bucket with 3 balls.
- {4} - 1 bucket with all 4 balls.

So the answer here is 5 different bucket options.

Comment: Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: It's like asking for the number of all possible combinations of numbers that add up to N (order doesn't matter).

Comment: @VitalyB, your comment sounds like an answer - p(n), right?

Comment: Yes, in the general case the answer is given by $p(n)$

Comment: You also need to have at least one ball in each bucket, right?